# Zend Server vs newrelic

Tags: zend-server, newrelic

I need to select one solution for deep monitoring of a production environment based on PHP and MySQL.

- Help us discover and recreate bugs that made it into the production environment
- Help us profile the application on real user patterns and hardware and discover real bottlenecks

I am between Zend Server and Newrelic.

I know Zend server offers much more than event monitoring but lets focus on that for this exercise.

I imagine Zend server can provide more details about the performance of specific functions when codetracing. On the other hand newrelic must have a broader set of reports and its new end user page load reports seem to be great for an end to end understanding of performance.

Has anyone worked with both? What is your experience?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience NewRelic is a better fit for your above mentioned needs.

As a standalone product NewRelic also looks much better on a long run, as they are adding new features and possibilities every few months.

That said - while NewRelic will play with any PHP + Mysql nicely, the real magical thing start only if you use one of the PHP frameworks, like - Wordpress, Magento etc.